# Networkx - graph & egdes attributes from csv file

Tags: python-3.x, networking, nodes, edges

First, my apologies because I think this question has been asked previously in other way.
I am just starting with Python (again...) and I am not familiar with all packages functionalities and reading codes
Here below is the basic code I want to start with but each time I try to add a specific detail, I fail.

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\n.philip\Documents\test_mine.csv",sep=";")
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='from', target='to',edge_attr=True)
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, node_color='Green',node_size=40, linewidths=10)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

my template is like this :

| from | to | edge_attr_1_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | C | 6 |
| A | E | 6 |
| B | A | 4 |
| B | C | 8 |
| B | D | 4 |
| B | E | 7 |
| C | A | 7 |
| C | B | 6 |
| C | D | 3 |
| C | E | 9 |
| D | A | 9 |
| D | B | 3 |
| D | C | 1 |
| D | E | 3 |
| E | A | 5 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVcwu.png)

My question is : how to exploit the column "edge_attributes_1" which is an integer to use it as a value for the relative thickness of the edge and while summed (the attribute is an integer) as the relative size of the nodes

I am afraid I mixe "propertie" of package which make my tries go wrong.
A true thank for your precious help

Comment: This is not a graph problem.  Please read tag descriptions before adding.

Comment: You need to tag with your language - python.

Comment: Template?  Do you mean input?  Question title says CSV but your 'template' is NOT CSV

Comment: thanks, I have added python and deleted "graph".. yes the file is a csv but when pasting the initial table it has appeared all in line which confused me : didn t find the upload button. yes you can consider it as input. the script does retrieve the data, my point is about adding specific attributes to nodes and manipulate edges..

Comment: I am more confused by your answer than by my question obviously.

Comment: It would also help if you ran spellcheck and fixed the several misspellings.